# Ĉu "se+us", aŭ "se+as"?

Tags: translation, verbs

> Duolingo tradukas l'anglan frazon "If I want to, I can!" al "Se mi vol**as**, mi pov**as**!".

Kial Duo ne tradukas tion al "vol**us**" kaj "pov**us**", anstataŭ "volas" kaj "povas"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la anglan, la frazo “se mi volus, mi povus” estus pli taŭge tradukita al “if I wanted to, I could”.

La du modaloj havas malsamajn signifojn. *Se +as* temas pri okazo kiu estas vere ebla aŭ eĉ probabla. Aliflanke, *se +us* estas pli imagata okazo. Ekzemple:

> Se la luno konsistus el fromaĝo, ni povus manĝi ĝin. *If the moon were made of cheese, we could eat it*.

Tio estas imagata fantazio.

> Se mia gasto estas vegetarano, mi rapide preparos pastaĵon por li.

Tio priskribas tute eblan okazon.

Do, en via ekzempla frazo, supozeble la parolanto priskribas ĝeneralajn okazojn kiam ri ja volas fari ion, kaj en tiuj okazoj ri ja povas fari ilin. La okazoj vere okazas kaj ne estas imagataj. Tial la as-tempo pli taŭgas.

Comment: Dankegon pro via helpo, Sinjor' Roberts!

Comment: Iomete kiel `kiam mi volas, mi povas`.

Answer (score 0):

Kial Duo ne tradukas tion al "volus" kaj "povus", anstataŭ "volas" kaj "povas"?

ĉar tio estus kondicionaloj: If I would want to I would be able to.  La frazo implicas ke mi nuntempe ne volas.

"Se mi volas mi povas" implicas ke foje mi jes volas/volos

Comment: "-us" ne estas kondicianalo en la senco de pluraj naciaj lingvoj, sed **imaga modo** kiel Neil Roberts jam konstatis. Tio signifas, ke la imagata afero ne (verŝajne) okazos. Kontraŭe "-as/is/os" estas **realaj modoj**, kio signifas, ke io vere okazis aŭ okazas resp. supozas, ke okazos. Kompreneble povas esti iu kondiĉo aŭ premiso, do "Se mi (vere) volas, mi (fakte) povas".